# get the values from javascript and display

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have my key values in java script inside my jsp like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var GROUP_OWNER_ID={7000000000000002551:"ABC",7000000000000004565:"ABCD"}
```

Now i will get the key(GROUP_OWNER_ID will have 7000000000000002551)  from ACtion class using below in jsp

```
<s:iterator value="vipSegmentLookup" >
                <tr>
<td class="table-db-results"><s:property value="GROUP_OWNER_ID"/></td>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
```

I want to get the corresponding value of that key and display in front end.ie i want to display ABC in front end through jsp.

How can i achieve this.

Comment: The key is to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - JSP on the server, when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser), and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response. In short: you cannot use JS variable in a JSP tag.

Comment: can we keep the values in property file and fetch it